# Apollo - multiple graphql subscriptions from child components in Angular app

Tags: angular, apollo, apollo-client

The general advice (in Apollo documentation) is to create small, focused queries inside child components.

So we have several such queries and they are all "live" queries where we listen for value changes.

We also have a graphql subscription that updates a part of the cache that is read by these queries.

So every time the subscription sends an update, the queries automatically update.

This works great but I'm not sure where should I subscribe to the subscription.

This is what we're doing now:

```
class AComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
    // Multiple instances of AComponent watch the same query.
    // Works great - one request is sent to the server and
    // all the others use the cache
    this.queryService1.watch()...
    // And we subscribe to a subscription that might update the cache
    // and cause the query to update
    this.subscription.subscribe();
  }
}
```

Since there are multiple instances of `AComponent`, is it ok that all of them subscribe to the subscription?

Comment: This looks like a use case for some store management, NgRx for example. But it would require some drastic refactor. Maybe some service with similar and simplified logic as NgRx can be used. You can inject the service if needed and you won't couple child and parent component using it like that.

Comment: @dallows Don't see how it solves the issue. The question still remains, where to subscribe to the subscription. In a single place or can it be done in multiple places without overhead

Comment: This is basically what NgRx does. You have a single source of truth to which you subscribe within every component that needs a slice of the state. So there is no problem with multiple subscriptions in components. Just instead of parent/top level component use a service for that.

Comment: But I'm asking about subscribing to graphql subscriptions. In other words, "activating" the subscription (asking the server to send us updates). 
I don't need NgRX as a single source of truth because I already have the Apollo cache for that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any code I'm just guessing but I would '*activate*' the subscription in a standalone service which can be initialized in some top level component. If you then want to access it in components, inject it as standard service.

```typescript
// app.component
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private apolloQueryService: ApolloQueryService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apolloQueryService.initialize();
  }
  //...
}

// ApolloQueryService
// I have no experience with Apollo, this is just to illustrate
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ApolloQueryService {
  apolloSub$;

  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {}

  initialize(): void {
    this.apolloSub$ = this.appolo.someQuery.subscribe();
    // add others if necessary
  }

  //...
}
```

Judging by your another question about observable splitting, this service can be then used to expose partial queries.

Comment: Thanks for investing the time in my questions :-). Your answer is wrong from several aspects. First, if all you want is a service to execute a query then you would extend Apollo's `Query` class. Second, I am asking about graphql subscriptions, not about queries. Third, and I hope you won't find it offensive, but if you have no experience in Apollo then probably you can't answer this question. I am well familiar with Angular, NgRX and so on. This question is about the right way to work with Apollo.

Comment: Non taken, but as I said, since you at first didn't provide any code it was quite difficult to figure out what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

After testing my solution I found out that you get an event for each time you subscribe to a subscription.

In our case, we subscribed multiple times to the same subscription and received multiple identical websocket messages.

In order to fix that we now wrap our subscriptions in a service that makes sure we only subscribe once:

```
class PostsUpdateService {
  private subscribed: boolean;

  constructor(private postsSubscription: Subscription<Post>) {}

  subscribe() {
    if (!this.subscribed) {
      this.subscribed = true;
      this.postsSubscription.subscribe().subscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

In our case, we are ok with never unsubscribing since we always have at least 1 live subscription.